# Could not find or load main class in Eclipse Spring boot project

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot

When i run a spring boot java project in eclipse , I am getting the below error.
Error: Could not find or load main class com.accenture.icoe.importdata.BatchImportMsApplication

Comment: Is build automatically selected? try cleaning the project twice. Or try restarting eclipse.

Comment: I tried doing clean build everything.. Still did not work

Comment: Try cleaning it twice in a row.

Comment: Where *is* that class?

Comment: Look at your project in the project/package explorer.  Are there any red marks in the project?  Is this a Maven-based project?  If so, is there a red mark on the pom.xml file?  If there's a red mark on the pom.xml file, then it likely refused to compile any source files. You have to make sure all the errors are gone from the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try below steps:

Step 1: **Project -> Clean**

Step 2: **Try updating the project by right-clicking on it. Maven -> Update Project**

Comment: After adding the below dependency in pom, I am getting this error.

<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0):

If user entry is deleted or any mistake then click on Restore Default Entries option in Run-> Run configurations -> Classpath. Then eclipse will restore the user entries. If default class path is not set then click on user entries under Classpath tab-> Add projects -> select your project name -> click ok. Now run it. This problem won’t come now if problem comes because of wrong class path.

If because of bootstrap entries then Click on Bootstrap entries in the Classpath tab-> Advanced -> then select Add library -> JRE system library -> OK

Run it then it error will gone.